# Submit SGE job array with random file names

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, job-scheduling, sungridengine

I have a script that was kicking off ~200 jobs for each sub-analysis. I realized that a job array would probably be much better for this for several reasons. It seems simple enough but is not quite working for me. My input files are not numbered so I've following examples I've seen I do this first:

```
INFILE=`sed -n ${SGE_TASK_ID}p <pathto/listOfFiles.txt`
```

My qsub command takes in quite a few variables as it is both pulling and outputting to different directories. $res does not change, however $INFILE is what I am looping through.

```
qsub -q test.q -t 1-200 -V -sync y -wd ${res} -b y perl -I /master/lib/ myanalysis.pl -c ${res}/${INFILE}/configFile-${INFILE}.txt -o ${res}/${INFILE}/
```

Since this was not working, I was curious as to what exactly was being passed. So I did an echo on this and saw that it only seems to expand up to the first time $INFILE is used. So I get:

```
perl -I /master/lib/ myanalysis.pl -c mydirectory/fileABC/
```

instead of:

```
perl -I /master/lib/ myanalysis.pl -c mydirectory/fileABC/configFile-fileABC.txt -o mydirectory/fileABC/
```

Hoping for some clarity on this and welcome all suggestions. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: It doesn't look like $SGE_TASK_ID is set on the cluster. I looked for any variable that could be used for an array ID and couldn't find anything. If I see anything else I will update again.

Comment: Try `echo $INFILE` for a start to see if your `sed` command is working. I would use `INFILE=$(grep "${SGE_TASK_ID}" pathto/listOfFiles.txt)`

Comment: How are you looping through `$INFILE`? The snippet seems to indicate that you are just using the whole variable. Perhaps you meant something like `for file in $INFILE; do qsub ... ; done`

Comment: By the way, don't use ALL_CAPS names for shell variables. Those are reserved for the system and the shell.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, I did do an echo. Both my sed command and the grep command you suggested provide the same result. For some reason, it still only expands only up to the first time $INFILE is used.

Comment: Hi @rici, I am trying to avoid submitting multiple individual jobs. That's why I am trying to understand how best to submit a job array. Originally I was submitting them pretty much just as you've suggested using a for loop.

Comment: There are just too many details missing from this question. Please be much more explicit about what you are doing. Remember that we cannot see over your shoulder and while it may appear obvious to you that a particular line is at a particular context in a particular file, please believe me that it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a grid engine variant then SGE_TASK_ID should be set within the job.  It looks like you are expecting it to be set to some useful variable before you use qsub.  Submitting  a script like this would do roughly what you appear to be trying to do:
 `#!/bin/bash
 INFILE=$(sed -n ${SGE_TASK_ID}p <pathto/listOfFiles.txt)
 exec perl -I /master/lib/ myanalysis.pl -c ${res}/${INFILE}/configFile-${INFILE}.txt -o  ${res}/${INFILE}/`

Then submit this script with

```
res=${res} qsub -q test.q -t 1-200 -V -sync y -wd ${res} myscript.sh
```

`

Comment: Thank you William. Yes, I misunderstood how/when the SGE_TASK_ID variable was set. I actually discovered this after inserting a bunch of echo statements to see what was going on. Ultimately I did exactly what you posted above. Many thanks for your response!